# Compare rows in Two Google Sheets, Once a match found Change Font Color

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to create two sheets: Sheet 1: a template into which a student will enter a translation of a word into a cell; Sheet 2: a key which checks it against all possible answers: The two sheets look like this:

[Here is a Link To Show the Two Spreadsheets](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E4YYImZQxpGHhNsU1RlY3CCKkU1yXE7Yq2QUWfv42ss/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to take the provided answer for each column in the template (A:1), and match it against all possible answers listed in the corresponding column in the key (if it matches anything between A:1:A:3 in the key).  If there's a match, the font should change to green and it should move to the next column.  If there's no match the font turns red before moving to the next column.

I've run the logger, and it seems like it iterates through the data from each sheet correctly.  The problem seems to be in comparing the 2 columns.

```
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ssA= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet = ssA.getSheetByName("Worksheet"); 
  var rangeData = worksheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = worksheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);

  var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jKuxXo6o5YJjSUrQmaHR0n1ydvw7PgUl29I9mtycF_g/edit#gid=0");
  var worksheetB = ssB.getSheetByName("Key");
  var rangeDataB = worksheetB.getDataRange();
  var lastColumnB = rangeDataB.getLastColumn();
  var lastRowB = rangeDataB.getLastRow();
  var searchRangeB = worksheetB. getRange(2, 2, lastRowB -1, lastColumnB -1);

  function onOpen(){
  ui.createMenu("Check My Translation.")
    .addItem("Check Set 1", "transcheck")
    .addToUi()
function transcheck(){   

//iterate through the two corresponding columns in template and reference sheet  
      for (i = 1; i < lastColumn; i++){
      for (j = 1; j < lastRow; j++){
//create the ranges to be compared and store as vars. cell and cellB          
          var cell = searchRange.getCell(j,i).getValue();
          var cellB =  searchRangeB.getCell(j,i).getValue();
//check for matches, change font accordingly           
             if (cell[0] === cellB[0]){
                  worksheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setFontColor("green");
            }else if(cell[0] =! cellB[0]){
                  worksheet.getRange(j+1,i+1).setFontColor("red");
```

I don't get any error messages; it just doesn't match the cells/change colors correctly.

Comment: Define `searchRange`, `searchRangeB` and `worksheet`.

Comment: I've added the complete code know so you can see how these are defined

Comment: `getValue()`returns `Object` not `Object[]`. So, `cell[0]` doesn't make sense. For performance, Please practice arrays and use `getValues()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several `}` missing at the end of your code and the correct operator is `!=` instead of `=!`. Also, as a user mentioned, getValue() function retrieves a single value and not an array as getValues() [1], which is the recommended function to use in this case to avoid hitting the Google quotas [2]:

```
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Check My Translation.")
  .addItem("Check Set 1", "transcheck")
  .addToUi()
}

function transcheck(){   
  var ssA= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet = ssA.getSheetByName("Worksheet"); 
  var rangeData = worksheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
  var searchRange = worksheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1).getValues();

  var worksheetB = ssA.getSheetByName("Key");
  var rangeDataB = worksheetB.getDataRange();
  var lastColumnB = rangeDataB.getLastColumn();
  var lastRowB = rangeDataB.getLastRow();
  var searchRangeB = worksheetB. getRange(2, 2, lastRowB -1, lastColumnB -1).getValues();
  //iterate through the two corresponding columns in template and reference sheet  
  for (var i = 0; i < searchRange.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < searchRange[0].length; j++){
      //create the ranges to be compared and store as vars. cell and cellB          
      var cell = searchRange[i][j];

      var k = 0;
      while(k<3) {
        var cellB =  searchRangeB[k][j];
        //check for matches, change font accordingly           
        if (cell == cellB){
          worksheet.getRange(i+2,j+2).setFontColor("green");
          break;
        }else if(cell != cellB){
          worksheet.getRange(i+2,j+2).setFontColor("red");
        }
        k++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Comment: Thanks, Andres!  Info. is extremely helpful as I am self-taught.  The code works as long as there is an exact match between row 1 in each spreadsheet.  Where I still have issues is:  A1 in the template (user provided data) can match any value between A1:A3 in the key.  If it doesn't match A1, it should test against A2, then A3.  Any time there's a match it should turn the text green and move to next column; it there is no match at all between A1 and A3, it should turn the text red then move on all the way through to the end.  No matter what I've tried, that stlll won't work.

Comment: Please show an example spreadsheet (a copy without private information) with what you're trying.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the spreadsheets to the original post; one is the user sheet; the other is the reference sheet.  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the code in the answer for that purpose. In any case, from now on you should be able to finish it by yourself. I it helped you please consider accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks.  The code works, but stills produces an error message after it runs: "TypeError: Cannot read property "0.0" from undefined."  From what I have researched, I think it centers on the line var cell = searchRange[i][j];  If I add some variation of searchRange[i] = [ ] to identify type as an array, it removes the error but the code stops working. Just need to figure out how to get rid of that error and still have the code function properly.

Comment: Just fixed the code. Note that lastcolumn and lastrow variables for both sheets are being taking as if the last column and row with data in the sheets are inside the data to be searched/matched. If they are not, change the values of those variables to the last columns and rows to be matched in each sheet.

Comment: Thanks!  This works-no more error message  I appreciate it.  I will accept as correct.